# How do I perform a callback on JQuery once it's loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm downloading JQuery asynchronously:

```
function addScript(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
addScript('jquery.js');

// non-jquery code ...

// jquery specific code like: $()...
```

As such - how do I call my JQuery specific code once JQuery is loaded (because since I'm downloading my JavaScript asynch - it's not blocking, which is good, but is trying to execute my JQuery specific code before JQuery has been loaded).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you loading scripts asynchronously?

Comment: Because I don't want them to block while downloading and responsiveness is super important.

Comment: Block what, exactly? The page load? If that's your concern, just put the code instantiation at the bottom of the page, right before the `</body>` tag...

Comment: @dclowd9901 In some cases, it is not necessary to load ever script at page load time.

Comment: Errrrr assigning script.src might be a blocking call... meaning that your JS execution is going to stop until the script is loaded.

Comment: @Polaris, nope; assigning to script.src won't block.

Comment: @dclowd9901 Just using a plain script tag at the bottom of the page without the async attribute blocks page render until the script loads. If the script times out you can freeze the page for a long time. If you include the async and defer attributes you can prevent the freeze time while waiting for network. It is true the script will block no matter what during execution, but this is often a much smaller fraction of time than the time to fetch the script over the internet.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini I replied to this question more than 2 years ago. I've since learned how to incorporate require.js for async loads, and techniques to concatenate the JS for fewer requests. I just thought you might like to hear that I made progress ;)

Comment: @dclowd9901 Excellent - came across this searching for a current problem, just thought I'd contribute for others who find it.

Answer (score 4):

You can host a copy of the jquery file yourself. Then you can add a call to the callback function at the bottom of jquery.js:

```
/* jquery code goes here ... */

my_onload_callback();
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this works (tested in FireFox 33.0.3):

```
    if(typeof(jQuery) == "undefined"){

        //create onload-callback function
        window["__9384nalksdfalkj04320"] = function(){
            console.log("jQuery=" + jQuery);
        };

        //load jQuery asynchronously
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("onload", "__9384nalksdfalkj04320();"); //register onload-callback listener function
        script.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js");
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inline [LabJs](http://labjs.com/documentation.php) into your page (potentially, every page). On the downside, you're inlining a script over and over. On the upside, LabJs is pretty small - 4k minified - and it lets you handle complex asynchrony load patterns cross-browser with very simple code like:

```
<script>
// Minified LabJs goes here
</script>
<script>
function init() {
    // Your code after jquery loads goes here
}

$LAB
.script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js')
.wait(init);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

<s>I'm not much on standard Javascript, but you may try doing something like this:</s>

```
var script_object = new addScript('jquery.js');

script_object.onLoad('addScript("my_jquery_related.js")');
```

Admittedly, that's a mega shot in the dark.

If that doesn't work, maybe pass through your function as a callback variable in your JS loader:

```
addScript(url, function(){ function_to_call();})

function addScript(url, call_back_function) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    call_back_function.call;
}
addScript('jquery.js');
```

That's all I got :\

Comment: I actually want to call a jquery function that already exists inline the HTML page. So it would be more like *script_object.onLoad(my_jquery_related_code())');*

Comment: @dclowd9901, I get an error, "script_object.onLoad is not a function"

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that'd happen. I think onLoad's only reserved for `window` or `document`. Updated answer with antoher option...

Comment: You can `return script` in your function, and `.onload = my_jquery_related_code` with the result similar to what you had originally :)

Comment: The call_back_function will be called before the script is loaded.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the head's up. Like I said, it was throwing spaghetti at a wall.

Comment: Also call_back_function.call should be call_back_function(). The use of the call method misses parentheses and is meaningless here.